# Thumbnails flickering on rollover with css transition

Tags: html, css, wordpress

The thumbnails that are called by using their Wordpress Post Featured Image seem to work fine, until I try to apply an opacity/saturation effect to them on rollover. When hovered over, 4 out of 5 of them "flicker". I think there may be something else in my code that is causing the glitch, because when I try to add another `<span>` or `<div>` to include the Post Titles within the thumbnails, they fail to appear correctly on the rollover as well.

Here's the CSS affecting the thumbs:

```
#columns {
    width: 90%;
    max-width: 970px;
    font-size: 16px;
    min-height: 300px;
    -moz-column-count: 5;
    -moz-column-gap: 5px;
    -moz-column-fill: auto;
    -webkit-column-count: 5;
    -webkit-column-gap: 5px;
    -webkit-column-fill: auto; 
    column-count: 5;
    column-gap: 5px;
    column-fill: auto;
    margin: 0 auto;
    overflow: auto;
}
.pin {
    -moz-column-break-inside: avoid;
    -webkit-column-break-inside: avoid; 
    column-break-inside: avoid; 
    position: relative;
    border: 0;
}
.pin img {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    margin: 5px 0 0 0;
}
.post-wrapper:hover img {
    -webkit-transition:all .4s;
    -moz-transition:all .4s;
    -ms-transition:all .4s;
    -o-transition:all .4s;
    transition:all .4s;
}
.post-wrapper:hover img {
    -webkit-filter:grayscale(100%);
    -moz-filter:grayscale(100%);
    -ms-filter:grayscale(100%);
    -o-filter:grayscale(100%);
    filter:grayscale(100%);
}
```

Here's the HTML for my home page:

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
<div id="main">

  <div id="columns">
  <?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
    <div class="pin">

        <span class="post-wrapper">
<a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail( $post_id, $size=0, $attr ); ?></a>
        </span>

    </div>
  <?php endwhile; ?> 
  <?php endif; ?>    
  </div>     

</div>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Here's the test site I'm working on to get a better idea:
http://cks.whiterabbitstudio.us/

I did already attempt to add `-webkit-transform:translate3d(0,0,0);` to `.post-wrapper:hover img` without much luck.

Comment: Do you have to use CSS3 Multiple column layout? I think it is not ready yet for development. I mean properties like `-webkit-column-count`.

Comment: The CSS3 Column layout was the only way I could get a masonry-type display to work on this site. You think I should find another solution?

Comment: I think for now you can use masonry jQuery plugin. http://masonry.desandro.com/

Comment: Thank you, Makshh. Masonry isn't working out for me... it puts all the thumbnails into one column and I've spent days trying to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is going to solve your issue but you are calling this JQuery code in your header (line 20) before you initiate your JQuery library (line 51) causing console errors.

```
jQuery(function() {
        jQuery( "div.gallery br" ).remove();
});
```

Second you are referencing a JS file that doesnt exist

```
http://cks.whiterabbitstudio.us/wp-content/themes/CKS/js/scripts.min.js?ver=4.3.1
```

I suggest clearing these issues up first and they may help you out with the hover issue.

Comment: I need that jQuery function for my responsive gallery thumbnails, and the super embarrassing thing is that I don't even know where those scripts are being inserted. They aren't in the header I created, and I checked the Functions.php file, but no luck.

Comment: WP includes a copy of the JQuery library file and adds it to the page. Look in your themes folder and I think its the header.php file were you will see the reference to the JQuery.js file. I suggest adding your code above the </head> or adding it to the functions.php

Comment: I imagine that the only place the file could be initially called from is in the Functions.php, because my header is nearly empty. However, when I attempt to delete the functions one-by-one to find the culprit, things get very ugly in regards to the design of my theme. I'm thinking I just need to reformat this theme!